# increase size of multiple histograms

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i have the following small multiples but i cannot increase their size. Anyone any idea on how to increase their size?

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
x = ['A']*300 + ['B']*400 + ['C']*300 + ['D']*500
y = np.random.randn(1500)
df = DataFrame({'Letter':x, 'N':y})
#plt.figure(figsize=(70,90))    
df['N'].hist(by=df['Letter'])
plt.show()
```

The output is this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bG4K.png)

Comment: `df['N'].hist(by=df['Letter'], figsize=(10, 10))`

Comment: Please review https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20, 10)
```